# How to correct sas dates after concatenating them

Tags: date, sas

```
compute calc1 /  character length=250 ;
name= 'new date';
calc1 = cats(PUT(_C4_,date9.),' ^n',PUT(_C5_,date9.),' ^n',PUT(_C6_,date9.));
endcomp;
```

I used the above code, but for some reason som dates are completely off.
This is an example of  the incorrect dates in the proc report output. Also the same column will have correct dates.

23AUG2068
21DEC2068

Any suggestions how to correct the dates?
Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more code in your question.  Add a data step to create some imaginary data that looks like your data, a few lines at least, and the complete proc report code here (enough to see the result that you're showing).  Likely the issue is your `PROC REPORT` or your data.

Comment: Also - I would verify that the dataset contains the proper values to begin with.  Being off by ~60 years suggests to me that you might have dates originating from Excel or MS product (1900 start date)  that weren't properly converted on import.

Comment: So first a create three variables date1, date2, date3, they contain the dates, then i use a define statement and instead of display, i use noprint option. This is what is causing the problem. If i substitute display instead of print the newdate displays correctly, but this causes proc report to display extra rows since the dates in the original table are in different rows, but i want them to be all in one row.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the information I requested ("edit" below the question) - do not add to comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have date times use dtdate9. format instead of date9.

```
calc1 = cats(PUT(_C4_,dtdate9.),' ^n',PUT(_C5_,dtdate9.),' ^n',PUT(_C6_,dtdate9.));
```

Comment: DT's would be a lot higher than just 2068... though a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: I was going off the comment that they're datetime20. format...but you are correct.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting (I hadn't seen the comment).  Maybe they're really *small* datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `_C4_`, `_C5_` and `_C6_` are dates, as opposed to datetimes or times?

Also, I'd try using putn instead of put.

Comment: Why would you use `putn`?  That allows you to specify the format at runtime, which can be helpful in some situations, but not sure why it would apply here.

Comment: ok if they are datetimes and not dates, that is probably your problem. try creating date4 = datepart(_C4_) [and same for date5/_C5_, date6/_C6_]. then replace your _C_ variables with your new date variables in your calc1 code above.